# Animation with CGAffineTransformScale freezes application

Tags: ios, scroll, core-animation

I am trying to implement a "disappearing" url bar, when the users scrolls in the webview.
The function below gets called in `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`.

For specific webpages the app freezes completely and uses 100% CPU. From trial and error we concluded that removing the `CGAffineTransformScale` fixes this. I am trying to understand why this happens and how else I could implement the same functionality.

```
- (void)collapseQueryBox
{

    _URLBarState = CLQURLBarStateCollapsing;
    _queryBoxViewHeightConstraint.constant = COLLAPSED_QUERYBOX_HEIGHT;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:COLLAPSE_ANIMATION_DURATION  animations:^{
        _webView.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
        _queryLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(_queryLabel.transform, COLLAPSE_ANIMATION_SCALE_FACTOR, COLLAPSE_ANIMATION_SCALE_FACTOR);
        _queryLabel.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
        [_browserContainerView layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        _URLBarState = CLQURLBarStateCollapsed;
    }];
}
```

The full stack trace of the paused app in the frozen state:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0xcbf9f, 0x025b40be libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 26, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
  * frame #0: 0x025b40be libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 26
    frame #1: 0x008cf411 Foundation`-[NSISEngine variableToWorkOnAmongVariablesWithIntegralizationViolationsIgnoringLostCauses:varsAlreadyAdjusted:] + 491
    frame #2: 0x00a41ea3 Foundation`__44-[NSISEngine fixupIntegralizationViolations]_block_invoke + 1285
    frame #3: 0x00a4368c Foundation`-[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 107
    frame #4: 0x008cf21a Foundation`-[NSISEngine withoutOptimizingAtEndRunBlockWithAutomaticOptimizationDisabled:] + 48
    frame #5: 0x008cf1d9 Foundation`-[NSISEngine fixupIntegralizationViolations] + 96
    frame #6: 0x008ceef8 Foundation`-[NSISEngine optimize] + 204
    frame #7: 0x008d57e3 Foundation`-[NSISEngine constraintDidChangeSuchThatMarker:shouldBeReplacedByMarkerPlusDelta:] + 336
    frame #8: 0x00a43e23 Foundation`-[NSISEngine tryToChangeConstraintSuchThatMarker:isReplacedByMarkerPlusDelta:undoHandler:] + 489
    frame #9: 0x00a4b2d5 Foundation`-[NSLayoutConstraint _tryToChangeContainerGeometryWithUndoHandler:] + 578
    frame #10: 0x008c8d4f Foundation`-[NSLayoutConstraint _setSymbolicConstant:constant:] + 384
    frame #11: 0x008cb6a1 Foundation`-[NSLayoutConstraint setConstant:] + 52
    frame #12: 0x00e398a5 UIKit`-[UIScrollView setContentSize:] + 566
    frame #13: 0x01030a5a UIKit`-[UITableViewCell _updateWrapperContentInset] + 117
    frame #14: 0x0103963a UIKit`-[UITableViewCell setFrame:] + 701
    frame #15: 0x00e1b7b0 UIKit`-[UIView(Geometry) _applyAutoresizingMaskWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 840
    frame #16: 0x00e1c552 UIKit`-[UIView(Geometry) _resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 290
    frame #17: 0x00e1c5aa UIKit`-[UIView(Geometry) resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 80
    frame #18: 0x00e1b185 UIKit`__46-[UIView(Geometry) resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:]_block_invoke + 87
    frame #19: 0x028a1d86 CoreFoundation`__53-[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 102
    frame #20: 0x028a1c5f CoreFoundation`-[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 239
    frame #21: 0x00e1b115 UIKit`-[UIView(Geometry) resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:] + 149
    frame #22: 0x00e19c4e UIKit`-[UIView(Geometry) setFrame:] + 559
    frame #23: 0x00e1b7b0 UIKit`-[UIView(Geometry) _applyAutoresizingMaskWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 840
    frame #24: 0x00e1c552 UIKit`-[UIView(Geometry) _resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 290
    frame #25: 0x00e1c5aa UIKit`-[UIView(Geometry) resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 80
    frame #26: 0x00e1b185 UIKit`__46-[UIView(Geometry) resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:]_block_invoke + 87
    frame #27: 0x028a1d86 CoreFoundation`__53-[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 102
    frame #28: 0x028a1c5f CoreFoundation`-[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 239
    frame #29: 0x00e1b115 UIKit`-[UIView(Geometry) resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:] + 149
    frame #30: 0x00eadc1a UIKit`-[UITableView resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:] + 98
    frame #31: 0x00e1c819 UIKit`-[UIView(Geometry) setBounds:] + 510
    frame #32: 0x00e39627 UIKit`-[UIScrollView setBounds:] + 1036
    frame #33: 0x00eadf5f UIKit`-[UITableView setBounds:] + 260
    frame #34: 0x00e1befd UIKit`-[UIView(Geometry) _applyISEngineLayoutValues] + 324
    frame #35: 0x00e1c4c0 UIKit`-[UIView(Geometry) _resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 144
    frame #36: 0x00e457bb UIKit`-[UIScrollView _resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 73
    frame #37: 0x00e1c5aa UIKit`-[UIView(Geometry) resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 80
    frame #38: 0x00e1b185 UIKit`__46-[UIView(Geometry) resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:]_block_invoke + 87
    frame #39: 0x028a1d86 CoreFoundation`__53-[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 102
    frame #40: 0x028a1c5f CoreFoundation`-[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 239
    frame #41: 0x00e1b115 UIKit`-[UIView(Geometry) resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:] + 149
    frame #42: 0x0145961c UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _is_layout] + 158
    frame #43: 0x00e20336 UIKit`-[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutSubviews] + 80
    frame #44: 0x00e2d964 UIKit`-[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 355
    frame #45: 0x025b682b libobjc.A.dylib`-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    frame #46: 0x01df345a QuartzCore`-[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
    frame #47: 0x01de7244 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 380
    frame #48: 0x01de70b0 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 26
    frame #49: 0x01d4d7fa QuartzCore`CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 294
    frame #50: 0x01d4eb85 QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::commit() + 393
    frame #51: 0x01d4f258 QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 92
    frame #52: 0x027ed36e CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
    frame #53: 0x027ed2bf CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoObservers + 399
    frame #54: 0x027cb254 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1076
    frame #55: 0x027ca9d3 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    frame #56: 0x027ca7eb CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    frame #57: 0x041895ee GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 192
    frame #58: 0x0418942b GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 104
    frame #59: 0x00dbef9b UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1225
```

Comment: Can you pause execution when the freeze starts and post the backtrace please?

Comment: How do I get the backtrace?I have the full stack trace at the side of the debugger view but how do I export it?

Comment: Screenshot it. Or type `bt` into the debugger console.

Comment: It's some AutoLayout issue. You should try to debug your constraints. I don't understand: you have a `UITableViewCell` with inside a `UIScrollView` with inside a `UIWebView`? Also, the web view itself has scrolling, maybe there is a way to hide the bar without wrapping it again.

Comment: I also get some random freezes of the app, suspect it's related with a path animation `CABasicAnimation` because sometimes the shape of the path appears distorted somewhere floating around. Were you able to find the solution to your problem?

Comment: Ideally you should not scale the SearchView directly, Instead you should take a snapshot of the SearchView, then hide the real bar instantly without animation or scale and scale the snapshotView with the desired animation It will always work smoothly and also won't mess with your real searchView.